# XCode 4 "Hide All Issues" on by default when opening a file

Tags: xcode4

When I am debugging and opening a new file, the issue are visible by default and it is very annoying.

I know that there is a menu item to hide all the issues in a file (Editor->Issues->Hide All Issues) but is there a way to set it by default.

Thanks in advance.

Kevin

Comment: does this setting persist between launches of Xcode or between projects that you open?

Comment: @Michael Dautermann: it does not persist even in the same project. If I open a file, hide the issues then close it and open it again the issues are back.